# How to merge two datetime column in one ? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I would like two transform two columns begin and end:

```
                         begin                          end
0                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688
1                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916
2  2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378                          NaN
3  2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764                          NaN
4                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
5  2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045                          NaN
6                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449
7  2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986                          NaN
8                          NaN  2019-10-21  08:32:37.004455
9  2019-10-21  08:32:35.755252                          NaN
```

into one column timestamp with an other column flag :

```
                     Timestamp                          Flag
0  2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688                           end
1  2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916                           end 
2  2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378                         begin
3  2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764                         begin
4  2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466                           end
5  2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045                         begin
6  2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449                           end
7  2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986                         begin
8  2019-10-21  08:32:37.004455                           end
9  2019-10-21  08:32:35.755252                         begin
```

But at the moment I can't find a solution to merge the two column begin and end into one.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
(df.stack()
 .rename_axis([None, 'Flag'])
 .reset_index(level=1, name='Timestamp'))
```

[out]

```
    Flag                    Timestamp
0    end  2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688
1    end  2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916
2  begin  2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378
3  begin  2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764
4    end  2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
5  begin  2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045
6    end  2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449
7  begin  2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986
8    end  2019-10-21  08:32:37.004455
9  begin  2019-10-21  08:32:35.755252
```

Comment: Just changed it to stack to realise that it's the same as you've done :-)

Comment: @Yatu, I did the exact same thing as you, tried `melt` and `dropna` first, but wasn't a fan of the ordering :)

Comment: Waouw @Chris A... Can you explain your code please. It's like magic for me 0_o

Comment: Sure, `stack`, just condenses all columns in a dataframe, to a single series - with the original column headers forming a `MultiIndex`. I used `rename_axis` here just so that when we `reset_index`, the "index name" carries over to the column name (Flag in this case). reset_index here just converts the single Series back to a DataFrame - moving the index levels into a column. The `rename` parameter of this method is passed as the column name (Timestamp in this case). Hope that helps

Comment: @ChrisA Why when I use stack() the number of rows increase?
Thanks for your help. So my question is, how to check if I have all the data since the result is different thanks to stack() ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.where()`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = np.where(df['begin'].isna(), df['end'], df['begin'])
df['flag'] = np.where(df['begin'].isna(), ['end'],['begin'])
```

If your null value `NaN` is a string instead, use it as your condition.